# Como colocar símbolo de € no DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Tenho uma DataGridView com valores numéricos e alguns deles representam valores monetários, mas do banco de dados vem apenas o número e queria colocar o símbolo da moeda na frente do valor.

Este é o código que uso para carregar a minha DataGridView;

```
public void carregarDataGridView3()
    {
        Abastecimento_Negocio abastecimento_Negocio = new Abastecimento_Negocio();
        dataGridView3.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView3.DataSource = abastecimento_Negocio.conusltarMedias(mesPassado);
        dataGridView3.Update();
        dataGridView3.Refresh();
        dataGridView3.ClearSelection();
        FontDataGrid3();
    }
```

A minha ideia era seleccionar a coluna que queria e concatenar o valor dentro da Cell com o símbolo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse dois valores queria colocar o símbolo da moeda, é possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a propriedade [DefaultCellStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.defaultcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) para definir o estilo a aplicar às células de uma determinada coluna.

Neste caso deve usar a propriedade [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
dataGridView3.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";
```

Substitua o índice de acordo com a coluna que quer formatar.

Por padrão o *provider* usado para a formatação é [CurrentUICulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

Caso queira usar um especifico use a propriedade FormatProvider:

```
dataGridView3.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-PT");
```

Sobre a string "C2" veja:

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)
- [Culture-Sensitive Formatting with Format Providers and the IFormatProvider Interface.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types#culture-sensitive-formatting-with-format-providers-and-the-iformatprovider-interface)

Comment: Já consegui, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Obrigado também por partilhar sobre a C2.